# dealing with double tabs in a tab delimited file in PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv, tabs

```
$lineArray = preg_split('/\t\s*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $line);
```

Above code snippet it to split a tab delimited file where tabs are not inside double quotes. It works fine except the cases where there double tabs (missing fields). Basically PHP sees only one tab when there are two. Is there a tab-width option?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're regular expressions and not a [tool built for the purpose](http://php.net/fgetcsv)?

Comment: WHat is the reason you have the \s* in there? It would include the tab... And what is the reason you can't use `str_getcsv` / `fgetcsv`?

Comment: it is not really a fully qualified csv and logic has more into it, but I narrowed it down to this not splitting correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \s will also match a tab and you apparently don't want that.

```
$lineArray = preg_split('/\t[ \r\n]*(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', $line);
```

should fix this problem by only matching non-tab whitespace.